# MYSQL Generated Stored columns with CASE

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to create a generated stored column in mysql with case and it is giving me error 'This is not yet supported for generated columns'.

```
ALTER TABLE user_character MODIFY COLUMN damage BIGINT GENERATED ALWAYS AS (
2*((`min_weapon_damage` + `max_weapon_damage`)/2) *(1 +
    (CASE
        WHEN `character_class_id` = '1' THEN (`character_current_lvl` + `class_strength` + `trained_strength` + `strengthaddprefix` + (`character_current_lvl` + `class_strength` + `trained_strength` + `strengthaddprefix`) * `strengthmultiprefix` / 100)
        WHEN `character_class_id` = '2' THEN (`character_current_lvl` + `class_agility` + `trained_agility` + `agilityaddprefix` + (`character_current_lvl` + `class_agility` + `trained_agility` + `agilityaddprefix`) * `agilitymultiprefix` / 100)
        WHEN `character_class_id` = '3' THEN (`character_current_lvl` + `class_intelligence` + `trained_intelligence` + `intelligenceaddprefix` + (`character_current_lvl` + `class_intelligence` + `trained_intelligence` + `intelligenceaddprefix`) * `intelligencemultiprefix` / 100)
    END)
    /10)
)
```

What am I missing?

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: If you want to *create a generated stored column* why did you use `MODIFY` and not `ADD`?

Comment: Please add table definition.